# How to get correct first letter in a tamil unicode word using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, tamil, xregexp

**Edit 2:**

```
const tamilRegex = XRegExp("\\p{Tamil}", "ug")
const match = XRegExp.exec(word, tamilRegex);
return match
```

Now, I found **XRegExp** a library which can handle unicode characters. The above code is the one I tried using that library still it returns wrong value.

Any help?!

---

**Edit 1:**

```
const word = "யாத்திராகமம்"
const firstLetter = word.match(/[^\w]/u)

console.log(firstLetter)
```

The above code returns `ய` which is not the correct first tamil letter in that word, instead it should be `யா`.

Any way to get the proper first letter in a word using regex or any other library?

Comment: Find list of letters in tamil unicode then compare with them using a loop.

Comment: `word.match(/^p{L}/u)`, check this library: http://xregexp.com/

Comment: @James_22 Yes, you are correct. But that would be reinventing the wheels. I hope there would be a solution already. If not will go with your solution. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Alex I have updated my question. Can you please check that again. I tried XRegExp library but I don't know how to properly write the regex for it. Can you help?

Comment: Actually the problem is that the first letter is ய, not யா. யா is a syllable composed of a consonant ய் and vowel ஆ : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%AE%AF%E0%AE%BE

Comment: @Alex Do you say that the word `யாத்திராகமம்` has the first letter as `ய` and not `யா`? I am sorry, I couldn't understand what you are trying to say?!. But the answer shared by @trincot worked for me. Thank you so much for your time & response @Alex. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the Tamil script, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_script) explains the concept of compound letters in that script. The Tamil [Unicode Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_script#In_Unicode) has characters in the range U+0B80 to U+0BFF, of which the subrange U+0BBE-U+0BCD, and one at U+0BD7 are suffixes that need to be combined with the preceding consonant to make it a compound letter.

Without any specialised library or smarter regex support, it seems you can make it work with the regex `[\u0b80-\u0bff][\u0bbe-\u0bcd\u0bd7]?`, which matches a character in the Tamil range, and in addition possibly one of those suffix codes.

```js
let s = "this is Tamil: யாத்திராகமம்";

console.log("First Tamil character: ", s.match(/[\u0b80-\u0bff][\u0bbe-\u0bcd\u0bd7]?/u));
```

Comment: this worked for me! Thank you so much for your answer.